# Unexpected behavior using `with` with CliBuilder

Tags: groovy

Given a script `test.groovy`

```
def cli = new CliBuilder().with {}
println cli

cli = new CliBuilder()
cli.with {}
println cli
```

when I run `groovy test.groovy`, the output is

```
null
groovy.util.CliBuilder@3c22fc4c
```

Why is the first output line `null`? Here is my `groovy --version` info:

```
Groovy Version: 2.4.3 JVM: 1.8.0_40 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `null` because `with(Closure c)` should return the `delegate` (here delegate being an instance of `CliBuilder`) which will be assigned to `cli`. Use as:

```
def cli = new CliBuilder().with { it }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the closure passed to [`with`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#with%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method, so `with` returns `null`, and `cli` in the first example becomes `null`.